# How to efficiently multiply bool matrix by double vector with Eigen 3?

Tags: c++, casting, matrix-multiplication, eigen3

I want to compute r=A*b, where A is a matrix containing about half 0's and half 1's, and b is a double vector.

```
MatrixXd Ad;
MatrixXb Ab; // bool matrix
VectorXd b, r;
```

I have tried:

```
1) Ad * b 
2) r(k)=Ab.row(k).transpose().array().select(b,0).sum()
3) Ab.cast<double>() * b
4) Ab.cast<double>().sparseView() * b
```

1 is faster than 2, 3 and 4, although 2 seems the most efficient. A is large (>10k * 1000k) in my project, so I do not want to use 1.

Is there a more efficient way to compute A*b than 1 with Eigen 3?

Thank you!

Comment: You may also try `Ab.cast<double>().lazyProduct(b)`. If method 1 is faster, I assume it does not include the conversion from `bool` to `double`?